# why scala doesn't make tail call optimization?

Tags: scala, continuations, tail-call-optimization

Just playing with continuations. The goal is to create function which will receive another function as parameter, and execution amount - and return function which will apply parameter given amount times.

The implementation looks pretty obvious

```
def n_times[T](func:T=>T,count:Int):T=>T = {
  @tailrec
  def n_times_cont(cnt:Int, continuation:T=>T):T=>T= cnt match {
        case _ if cnt < 1 => throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"count was wrong $count")
        case 1 => continuation
        case _ => n_times_cont(cnt-1,i=>continuation(func(i)))
      }
  n_times_cont(count, func)
}

def inc (x:Int) = x+1

    val res1 = n_times(inc,1000)(1)  // Works OK, returns 1001

val res = n_times(inc,10000000)(1) // FAILS
```

But there is no problem - this code fails with StackOverflow error. Why there is no tail-call optimization here?

I'm running it in Eclipse using Scala plugin, and it returns
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger(Unknown Source)
        at Task_Mult$$anonfun$1.apply(Task_Mult.scala:25)
        at Task_Mult$$anonfun$n_times_cont$1$1.apply(Task_Mult.scala:18)

p.s.

F# code, which is almost direct translation, is working without any issues

```
let n_times_cnt func count = 
    let rec n_times_impl count' continuation = 
        match count' with
        | _ when count'<1 -> failwith "wrong count"
        | 1 -> continuation
        | _ -> n_times_impl (count'-1) (func >> continuation) 
    n_times_impl count func

let inc x = x+1
let res = (n_times_cnt inc 10000000) 1

printfn "%o" res
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the JVM prevent tail call optimizations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105834/does-the-jvm-prevent-tail-call-optimizations)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Scala standard library *has* an implementation of trampolines in `scala.util.control.TailCalls`. So revisiting your implementation... When you build up the nested calls with `continuation(func(t))`, those are tail calls, just not optimized by the compiler. So, let's build up a `T => TailRec[T]`, where the stack frames will be replaced with objects in the heap. Then return a function that will take the argument and pass it to that trampolined function:

```
import util.control.TailCalls._
def n_times_trampolined[T](func: T => T, count: Int): T => T = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def n_times_cont(cnt: Int, continuation: T => TailRec[T]): T => TailRec[T] = cnt match {
    case _ if cnt < 1 => throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"count was wrong $count")
    case 1 => continuation
    case _ => n_times_cont(cnt - 1, t => tailcall(continuation(func(t))))
  }
  val lifted : T => TailRec[T] = t => done(func(t))
  t => n_times_cont(count, lifted)(t).result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong here but I suspect that the `n_times_cont` inner function is properly converted to use tail recursion; the culprit's not there.

The stack is blown up by the collected `continuation` closures (i.e. the `i=>continuation(func(i))`) which make 10000000 nested calls to your `inc` method, once you apply the result of the main function.

in fact you can try

```
scala> val rs = n_times(inc, 1000000)
rs: Int => Int = <function1> //<- we're happy here

scala> rs(1) //<- this blows up the stack!
```

---

As an aside, you can rewrite

`i=>continuation(func(i))`

as

`continuation compose func`

for the sake of greater readability

Comment: As I understand the whole idea of CPS is this collection of closures.
But it looks like Scala just cannot make such construct working.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549433/is-it-possible-to-use-continuations-to-make-foldright-tail-recursive?rq=1

p.s. Thanks for compose trick, I didn't know about that

Comment: Yeah, you want that `i => ...` lambda to make a tail call to `continuation`, which `@tailrec` isn't going to do for you and nor is anything else in Scala land. You can build your own trampoline, I guess :)

Comment: @MyseriousDan, well, "anything else in Scala land" may be a strong statement. The standard library has `util.control.TailCalls`...

Comment: @huynhjl hah, that's more or less what I meant by build your own trampoline :)